# SharePoint 2010 FBA - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: forms-authentication

I Converted a sharepoint 2010 web application which has default zone and Extranet zone to use claims based authentication instead of classic mode. I followed this article http://bit.ly/bvv3CT to convert an existing application to claims based authentication and then this article http://bit.ly/9StUpd to configure asp.net sql membership provider as identity provider.

The windows authentication site is working fine if I browse the web application in the server. But if try to access the Extended site through internet it shows 401 unauthorized exception. I dont even get the login screen...

Have anyone come across this situation...

Comment: I vote to move this to SharePoint.SE

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve my issue, I was also facing the same issue and saw this forum, but did not find an answer. I found an answer and thought it might help someone!

I was actually extending the site as HTTPS, so I thought may be the issue was that. So I deleted that site and extended it as a normal HTTP site with FBA authentication. Now I saw the login page, but when I gave user name/pwd it did not sign in. I realized that the FBA user  was not having access, at least one FBA user, maybe the admin, etc., has to be set as owner on the SiteCollection. My owners were all NT guys, none from the FBA.

1. So, I changed the NT site to allow FBA access as well (So I can find FBA admin1 to give him access)
2. Then I logged on the site as windows authentication/NT guy and added one FBA user admin1 as owner (you can add in any group, I was just testing)
3. Then I disabled FBA on NT site (Because I don't need internal users to see the Options of logging as NT or FBA)
4. Now when I open the extended FBA site, it gives me a login prompt and admin1 can log in! Viola!!

Note: I know there might be a question why the login Page does not come up even without admin1 having access as authentication is secondary, but I don't know. May be cause the site only had NT guys with access, since I chose FBA, it did not find any reason to submit the login page? Since all users were only integrated authentication guys, and I chose not to use integrated authentication, it just directly says "401 Unauthorized"!

Comment: Hi Sachin, Thanks for replying to this question. The problem we had in setting up FBA is the app pool identity was using windows NT user accont instead of a dedicated service account and few other issues. We properly gave user's access rights and fixed few other issues it is sorted out now.

Comment: I have having the same issue... but friends i am little confused with your answer...
if you can explain me more detail then would be better for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a silly question, but are you using credentials that are configured in the ASP.NET SQL membership database?

Sounds like the user you are using doesn't have permissions.

Comment: Hi TroyB30, I have added the app pool identity of Central admin and web application to the asp.net membership database. What permission do I need to set... can you be more clear...

Comment: Are you using forms based authentication?

What username and password are you logging into the website with?

Comment: Hi TroyB30, Yes I'm using forms based authentication. But I'm not even getting the FBA sign in page. I have added the app pool identity account of web app and central admin to the aspnetdb database permission.

Comment: What url are you requesting? http://servername/default.aspx? Does the same thing happen if you go to http://servername//_layouts/viewlsts.aspx. Are there any errors in the server event log when this happens?